# How to use Auto Wiring in spring for two beans?

Tags: spring

I am new to apply Auto Wiring for two beans.please check my code below

**Color.java**

```
public class Color {

private String baseColor;

private String textureColor;

public String getBaseColor() {
    return baseColor;
}

public void setBaseColor(String baseColor) {
    this.baseColor = baseColor;
}

public String getTextureColor() {
    return textureColor;
}

public void setTextureColor(String textureColor) {
    this.textureColor = textureColor;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return baseColor + " base skin color and " + textureColor + " texture color." ;

}
```

}

**Behaviour.java**

```
public class Behaviour{

private String behaviourType;



public String getBehaviourType() {
    return behaviourType;
}

public void setBehaviourType(String behaviourType) {
    this.behaviourType = behaviourType;
}


}
```

**Cat .java**

```
public class Cat {

private String name;

private Color color;
    private Behaviour behaviour;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color= color;
}
public Color getBehaviour() {
    return behaviour;
}

public void setBehaviour(Behaviour behaviour) {
    this.behaviour= behaviour;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "The " + name + " has " + color.toString();

}
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="color" class="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.Color">
        <property name="baseColor" value="white" />
        <property name="textureColor" value="grey" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cat" class="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.Cat">
        <property name="name" value="cat" />
        <property name="color" ref="color" />
               <property name="behaviour" ref="behaviour" />
    </bean>
          <bean id="behaviour" class="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.Behaviour">
        <property name="behaviourType" value="Somebevhaviour" />

     </bean>
   </beans>
```

It's working fine but i want to apply dependency  by using Auto Wiring (byName) any one help for writing the applicationContext.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example site ( http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-by-name/ ), try that sample code to learn this.

For example. your cat bean can be auto wire as below, so your color and behaviour  beans will be auto wired.

```
<bean id="cat" class="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.Cat" autowire="byName">
        <property name="name" value="cat" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class as follows.

**Cat.java**

```
@Component
public class Cat {

    @Value("${cat.name}")
    private String name;

    @Autowired
    private Color color;

    @Autowired
    private Behaviour behaviour;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Behaviour getBehaviour() {
        return behaviour;
    }

    public void setBehaviour(Behaviour behaviour) {
        this.behaviour = behaviour;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "The " + name + " has " + color.toString();

    }
}
```

**Behaviour.java**

```
@Component
public class Behaviour {

    @Value("${behaviour.behaviourType}")
    private String behaviourType;

    public String getBehaviourType() {
        return behaviourType;
    }

    public void setBehaviourType(String behaviourType) {
        this.behaviourType = behaviourType;
    }

}
```

**Color.java**

```
@Component
public class Color {

    @Value("${color.basecolor}")
    private String baseColor;

    @Value("${color.textureColor}")
    private String textureColor;

    public String getBaseColor() {
        return baseColor;
    }

    public void setBaseColor(String baseColor) {
        this.baseColor = baseColor;
    }

    public String getTextureColor() {
        return textureColor;
    }

    public void setTextureColor(String textureColor) {
        this.textureColor = textureColor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return baseColor + " base skin color and " + textureColor
                + " texture color.";

    }
}
```

Now create app.properties file with following properties

```
cat.name=billy
behaviour.behaviourType=sobor
color.basecolor=white
color.textureColor=black
```

Finally modify your application context file as follows.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kp"></context:component-scan>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:app.properties"/>
```

And remove the beans you had defined. Since you have distinct class types no need to Autowire by name